# Style by tag in a div tag

Tags: html, css, xhtml

not sure if this is possible but, can you style a single tag within a div tag? EG, could i put a `<div>` around a section of my page then say make all `<h2>` tags green? is this possible or do you have to use classes?
thanks

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking.  Please revisit your question and try to make it clearer.

Comment: This should help: I made the tags visible in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking correct, then yes, it is possible. [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/DEUJa/). For more information, read up on [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html).

On re-reading the question, the only way to style an arbitrary element within a div is by using either classes or id (with CSS selectors). [Here's another example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZsDqy/1/) styling a single item using selectors.

Answer (score 2):

For any single *arbitrary* element you *must* use an ID or a single-use class and select that:

```
#green-headings h2 { color: green; }
```

However, if there is some structural information about your `<div>` that can be queryable with CSS selectors, you can use CSS pseudo-classes without needing to add an ID or class to your markup. For example, if your `<div>` is always the first child of `body`:

```
body > div:first-child h2 { color: green; }
```

Answer (score 1):

background to green HTML

```
<div> 
   <p>hello everyone!</p>
   <div> hi. i'm a green bgd box</div>
   <p>nice. i don't have background.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div > div {background-color: green}
```

Comment: That will make all divs that are a direct child of another div have green backgrounds.

Comment: Yep. Based on the questions simplicity i did not suppose he wants to make a div which append some other divs, filled by ajax, unbind the some events rebind them and then set their background-color to green. :P

Comment: on `<div id="test"><h2>Stuff</h2></div>` will be `#test h2`.